# How to replace text sequences ending in a fixed pattern within a long text string in R?

Tags: r, replace

I have a column within a data frame containing long text sequences (often in the thousands of characters) of the format:

```
abab(VR) | ddee(NR) | def(NR) | fff(VR) | oqq | pqq | ppf(VR)
```

i.e. a string, a suffix in brackets, then a delimiter

I'm trying to work out the syntax in R to delete the items that end in (VR), including the trailing pipe *if present*, so that I'm left with:

```
ddee(NR) | def(NR) | oqq | pqq
```

I cannot work out the regular expression (or gsub) that will remove these entries and would like to request if anyone could help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `gsub`, you can remove the pattern in two stages:

```
gsub(" \\| $", "", gsub("\\w+\\(VR\\)( \\| )?", "", s))
# firstly remove all words ending with (VR) and optional | following the pattern and 
# then remove the possible | at the end of the string

# [1] "ddee(NR) | def(NR) | oqq | pqq"
```

- regular expression `\\w+\\(VR\\)` will match words ending with `(VR)`, parentheses are escaped by `\\`;
- `( \\| )?` matches optional delimiter `|`, this makes sure it will match the pattern both in the middle and at the end of the string;
- possible `|` left out at the end of the string can be removed by a second `gsub`;

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using `strsplit` and `paste` with the collapse argument:

```
paste(sapply(strsplit(temp, split=" +\\| +"),
        function(i) { i[setdiff(seq_along(i), grep("\\(VR\\)$", i))] }),
  collapse=" | ")
[1] "ddee(NR) | def(NR) | oqq | pqq"
```

We split on the pipe and spaces, then feed the resulting list to `sapply` which uses the `grep` function to drop any elements of the vector that end with "(VR)". Finally, the result is pasted together.

I added a subsetting method with `setdiff` so that vectors without any "(VR)" will return without any modification.

Comment: I realise that I also have entries where there is just a single entry, i.e. no pipe delimiter. Is there an easy way to modify the method to account for "single" items? e.g.   "abc"   OR  "abc(VR)"

Comment: @Jon I modified the code so that it should work for this situation.